# When I upload music track into raw folder in android studio it is showing an error

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

I am getting an error like this as I mentioned in the above screenshot and like when I double click it or when I run the application it is showing an error like this.

Comment: You can't play audio in Android studio.

Comment: play this Om.mp3 with mediaPlayer().. You can't play this file with Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

- You cant play audio in android studio.
- make name to small letters and clean your project.
- now implement a player and set raw resource to play your audio